# Installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not going ahead in laptop ACER Aspire A514-54G

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, laptop, acer, aspire

Installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not going ahead in laptop ACER Aspire A514-54G, after selection of the language. The touchpad is not working at all.

Comment: Looking at the specs for that machine, you *might* want to try Ubuntu 20.10, as it would have the more recent kernel to handle some of the hardware in your notebook.